# css right sidebar height 100%

Tags: css, height, footer, sidebar

I found few tutorials on 100% height and sticky footer.
However, I am not able to implement 100% height right sidebar.
The height of my sidebar seems to be relevant to the content inside the sidebar, even it's set 100%.
Any ideas?

Here's my html

```
    <body>
    <div id="container">
<div id="header">
</div>
   <div id="wrap">
        <div id="sidebar-right">
            <div id="menu">
                  lorem ipsum
              </div>
        </div>
        <div id="content">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus adipiscing, nunc quis vehicula vehicula, mi nunc tempor lorem, nec congue augue neque vitae augue. 
   </div>
<div class="push"></div>
</div>
<div class="footer">
</div>
</body>
```

And CSS

```
html, body{margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 100%;}
#sidebar-right{
    background: #ccc;
    float: right;
    height: 100%;
    width: 300px;
    border-left: 2px #fff solid;
}
#container{
height: auto !important;
    margin: 0 auto -142px;
    min-height: 100%;
}

#wrap {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    }

#menu {margin: 150px 0 0 50px;} 

.footer {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #BA6F19;
    clear: both;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
}   

#header {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #BA6F19;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 20px;
}
#content {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 100px;
    width: 400px;
    height: 100%
    }
.footer, .push {
    height: 142px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#sidebar-right{
    background: #ccc;
    float: right;
    height: 100% !important;
    width: 300px;
    border-left: 2px #fff solid;
}
```

try this?

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't yet solve the problem. You can see the site here: http://tndsigns.com/test/height/

Comment: I think you can make height: 400px. (i am sorry so my english is bad)

Comment: This wouldn't work either, since it would make it fixed height.

Comment: Hi, look [here](http://www.ejeliot.com/blog/61) for possible way, how this can be achieved. You can add `padding-bottom: 2000px; margin-bottom: -2000px;` and remove the `height:...` setting from the `#sidebar-right`, and let the `#wrap { overflow:hidden}` be as it is now, then the right column will stretch as you expect.

Comment: So in my case, I would like the sidebar go all the way down (to footer) regardless of the wrap container height. I still haven't found a good solution. Any other ideas?